# OpenGL/GLSL - Per pixel fog in outdoor environments

Tags: opengl, glsl

Using the fixed function pipeline, I was able to set the clear color as the same color as fog and enable fog perfectly. Now that I am using shaders, I know I will need to use GLSL to apply fog. The problem I am having understanding is that if the pixel shaders only run on every pixel of each rasterized polygon, how do I force it to run on areas where there is no polygons? Do I just set the clear color matching the fog? Do I need a skydome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way as it did before. If your background is just the clear color, then your clear color should match the fog color.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicol said, is should work as is with little modifications.

So how do you go? set your clear color to be the far end fog color, and then I would suggest to have the fog component function integrated into your pixel/fragment shader.
This way you can play with the equation of the fog to be as complicated as you want including non-linear and relying on stochastic noise that will allow introduction of 'volumetric area fog effect' (so that some areas might look a bit more foggy than others in a 'cloudy' manner). The later effect can easily be done by adding reading a screen coordinate texture that specifies a fog equation or noise (or look up into fog ratio).

Good luck